# would there be a more shorter version for finding keys from dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to extract keys from dictionary that has corresponding values to some input.

below is my code

```
decoded_text = ""
for code in refined_code:
    for key, value in codebook.items():
        if value == code:
            decoded_text += key

return decoded_text
```

I was just wondering if there would be a sophisticated way to write such code.

Comment: @what is `codebook` is it the same as `code`?

Comment: Don't use a dict if you need to lookup by *value*.

Comment: No, dict objects map keys to values, if you want a key for a given value, you have no choice but to iterate

Comment: @Imiguelvargasf codebook is a dictionary that has list of keys and corresponding decryption

Comment: If you have a lot to do, you might want to invert `codebook` first and the. Use it as a dictionary. Also, you don’t want to keep appending to a string: better to `””.join(codebookInv[code] for code in refined_code)` I think. Where `codebookInv = dict((value, key) for key, value in codebook)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a comprehension. However, I recommend reading [this article](https://treyhunner.com/2019/03/abusing-and-overusing-list-comprehensions-in-python/). Sometimes because comprehensions are cool, we tend to over use them.

Try the following:

```
return ''.join(key for key, value in codebook.items() for code in refined_code if value == code)
```